# Adding markups to your href

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<p>Steps: <a id="steps"></a></p>
<a href='save.php?id=<a id="steps"></a>'><button class="btn-2">Save</button></a>
```

^the code doesnt work

This is the code. a javascript is always changing the number in `<a id="steps"></a>`
But I need to open a new page save.php?id=latest number.

Because later im doing

```
$steps = $_GET['id'];
echo $steps;
```

Comment: html code is with php in above

Comment: yes the html code is in php.

Comment: its confusing `<a href='save.php?id=<a id="steps">`

Comment: @Bamuel What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function savestep(){
    var x = document.getElementById('steps').innerHTML;
    void window.open('save.php?id=' + x,'_self',false);
}
```

Made a variable x = id=step.innerHTML then therefore made open new page 'save.php?id=' + x

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the steps when the user clicks save. This would be a cleaner solution. Also, use a `<span>` instead of an `<a>`

```
<p>Steps: <span id="steps"></span></p>
```

Then later you can use jquery POST request

```
function saveSteps()
{
    var steps = parseInt($("#steps").text());
    $.post("save.php", {id: steps}, function(result){
    //Whatever you want to do, or just don't do anything
});
```